# calling/executing unix scripts on windows with cygwin

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file, cygwin

Imagine you have a program or script which calls shell scripts or commands on Unix/Linux.

For example, php example:

```
<?php
$call = system('./myscript.ksh', $retval);
?>
```

Now, that PHP script is being moved to windows.

Will installing cygwin allow system calls like "./script.ksh" to work, 
or will it need changed to something like "cmd /c script.ksh"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could associate `.ksh` files with `c:/cygwin/bin/ksh.exe` this way:

- right click a `.ksh` file
- Open with...
- Browse to and select `c:/cygwin/bin/ksh.exe`
- Make sure you check `Always use this program to open this kind of file`

Test the above procedure by double-clicking the `.ksh` file.

I think your original PHP code should work after this. But try it first, I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: I guess for the given example this will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that SzG's answer will work. It may. And if it does, it's probably the easiest way.

However, you should be able to get this working exactly as you want by installing the Cygwin version of PHP. Unfortunately, it's not one of the regular Cygwin packages, but it is available from Cygwin Ports. You can get the instructions on how to install that from the Cygwin Ports home page: http://cygwinports.org/.